# Invitation system (push) for web app

Tags: php, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

I am creating an web app and a user can start a game with multiple players (your friends). This game is played on 1 device. Is it possible that all invited players get a notification on their device where they can accept or decline the invitation ?

So in steps

- Player 1 creates a game and invites player 2 and 3
- Player 2 receives a notification on his mobile device and presses accept, he is added as player of that game
- Player 3 doesn't have a device and enters his PIN to accept his participation.

The step that I want to have is step2.
I have read about OneSignal who can send push notifications to specific users, but I could not find if you can send a response back (accept or decline). Or is there an other way (without to have a native app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is understood but at this moment a little too broad. But. I will try to answer in concept also :)

Now...you said you already know how to send target specific notification with OneSignal.

What you need to do from now one it cloud be like this:

- Attach a link or click or action to that invite. Or when such invite
  arrived open a particular view in the app/web/application that you are developing and revives the link.
- Attach the session/game/user/object ID to that link and send the call
  to you API (which is based on your server). If you have an API, if you don't you can have a very simple API build to handle only such requests with URL xxxx.com/path/to/api/call/var1/var2/var3/etc
- From there you can catch the request and reply or adapt accordingly on your server side.

Maybe this Framework can help you to speed up the API dev in PHP. [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) can do that trick.

You can follow this tutorial [here](https://coderexample.com/restful-api-in-lumen-a-laravel-micro-framework/) for a fast API development with it.

Comment: Thanks, that's clear for me. So the form that creates the game should have a listeren. So when a user clicks on the link, it should update the list with player X accepted. (like a game lobby where you click I am ready and when everybody is ready, the game can start).
And if there is another tool who can do above, please :)

Comment: like a "lobby" in terms of concept but exactly like an API to do the "listening" - "response". Lumen is and example. I am updating the answer above with two links that can help you

Comment: Thanks for the information, gonna try it out and using your way.

Comment: glad I cloud help! still if you face issues let me know ;) we only discussed in theory and fro here to practice are many different exited and some unknown roads :D :) so ...anytime ;)